# How do I use navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) inside of a closure with no warnings and errors?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, swift3, closures

I know that in swift 3 that this:

```
navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

will produce this warning:

```
"Expression of type "UIViewController?" is unused"
```

and I know the recommended way to rid myself of this warning is to do the following:

```
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

However when that is inside of a closure:

```
myFunction(myParams: ["blah", "bleh"], callback: { myResult in
_ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
})
```

I get this error:

```
Implicit use of 'self' in closure; use 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
```

and if I do this:

```
myFunction(myParams: ["blah", "bleh"], callback: { myResult in
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
})
```

I'm back to getting the warning:

```
"Expression of type "UIViewController?" is unused"
```

How do I go about using navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) inside of a closure with no warnings and errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were nearly there! It's just combining what you already had to produce:

```
myFunction(myParams: ["blah", "bleh"], callback: { myResult in
    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
})
```

Comment: Well, duh!! sheesh, that was driving me nuts, thanks!